# Hangfire Autofac .net core 3.1

Tags: .net-core, autofac, hangfire

I am using Hangfire.Autofac and trying to configure it based on the documentation:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseAutofacActivator(builder.Build());
```

But I get the following exception:

> Build() or Update() can only be called once on a ContainerBuilder

I am new to .Net Core, how do I enable the `Autofac` Configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you call following method once: `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseAutofacActivator(builder.Build());`

So basicly, you need create your builder

`var builder = new ContainerBuilder();`

Then add all dependencies

`builder.RegisterType<Database>().InstancePerBackgroundJob();`

and after this call `Build()` method. It depends on your app, where call this method better. If you craete a web application, call it in `Startup` class.